# what is object to be geocoded and an array of Geocoder::Result objects in geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am trying to use geocoder gem but confused while using reverse geocoding.

I have "region" model with fields- country, state, city and zipcode.

If user fill only zipcode then i want to fill all other field automatically.

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
  if geo = results.first
    obj.city    = geo.city
    obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code
    obj.country = geo.country_code
  end
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

but unable to understand what obj and result is and how to set obj and result.

please help me by giving example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have written a [blog](http://milind300.blogspot.com/2014/12/using-geocoder-to-get-street.html) explaining how it works.you need to geocode and get the relevant informations from `geocoder` gem.

User will enter address using Geocomplete and store that address in address column in users/locations table
Then,use Geocoder to fetch other geo informations and update other columns using address.

Here it goes................

**================users/locations table,here i will use the allow the user to fill in the address using Geocomplete and then use it to get other details using Geocoder**

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :places do |t|
      t.string :address
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
      ##======here the address field is important==========
      t.string :address
      t.string :country
      t.string :state
      t.string :city
      t.string :pincode
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :places, :address
  end
end
```

**==================Geocode to autopopulate using address in users/location model**

```
##i want to use the address column to autopopulate others columns
geocoded_by :address
##also i want to use the latitude.longitude to fetch all others informations and then save in relevant ##feilds
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
  if geo = results.first
    obj.state    = geo.state
    obj.city    = geo.city
    obj.pincode = geo.postal_code
    obj.country = geo.country
  end
end
```

**##change/update/validate address only if address changed to improved performance else every time it ##will keep updating**

```
after_validation :geocode, :reverse_geocode ,:if => :address_changed?
```